# Op amp stability problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, crystal

I'm trying to measure the dynamic response of a 16MHz crystal using a pair of op amps as shown below

[image]

Spice simulations predict that this should work fine. Experimentally, however, this configuration is unstable with both op amps drawing a large current and producing high-frequency (~70MHz) large-amplitude output (~3V). Does anybody have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Edit: Adding board diagrams. The diagram above is actually a simplified model from a larger board (but isolated from the remainder of the board, which has been disconnected while debugging this issue), but the line going to the right on the first diagram connects directly to the crystal in the second (I removed some unnecessary parts in between for clarity). The amplifier on the left seems to work on its own when the other is disconnected with the negative input shorted to ground, so I'm guessing it's either something wrong the second circuit or from the two op amps interacting. The component labeled VC4 was replaced with a 0-ohm resistor between pads 1&2 for debugging and the 1M resistor was removed as well.

[image]

Comment: How's your decoupling?

Comment: I have a 4.7uF and 100nF capacitor on each rail for decoupling

Comment: How close is it to the IC?

Comment: As close as i could feasibly get it. About 1-3mm

Comment: In fact, can you post your board layout here?  Fast parts tend to be quite sensitive to it...

Comment: You may need a small cap across the feedback resistors to compensate for capacitance at the inverting input.

Comment: I added the layout to the post. I tried adding a 15pF capacitor across the feedback resistor on the right as well as swapping the 110-ohm with a 1k resistor but it didn't change much

Comment: The electrical connection between the caps on the +5 V supply and the ground pin of the chip is pretty long. The resonant frequency of those caps is likely to be well below 1 MHz.  Is there any reason you can't use a ground fill on the yellow layer instead of tracks?

Comment: Isn't AMP1 meant to be a SOT23 package? If it's a mistake on the schematic you've posted then NOW IS THE TIME to take the uncertainty out of this question and totally post the correct schematic. I want part references on this schematic.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit, with 900MHz LMH6609, needs a ground plane. The resistors also need to be of low value. In the TI datasheet, 250 Ohms is the recommended feedback R value.

Additionally, a cap from +VDD to -VDD, under the IC, is recommended.